# NtReadFile doesn't read

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, code-injection

I try to write dll injector with nativeApi. My first question is this good way to do it?
And second is: NtReadFile doesn't fail, but also doesn't read. I think it's buffer wrong but i'm not sure? How can i fix this issue?

Now it's look like this:

```
bool initiationDll(const std::string& dllPath){
if (!isDllExist(dllPath))
{
    printf("Dll doesn't exist!\n");
    return false;
}
else
{
printf("LibraryPath :%s\n", dllPath.c_str());

NTSTATUS status; 
HANDLE lFile;

OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objAttribs = { 0 }; 
UNICODE_STRING unicodeString;
std::string dllPathWithprefix = "\\??\\" + dllPath;
std::wstring wString = std::wstring(dllPathWithprefix.begin(), dllPathWithprefix.end()); PCWSTR toPcwstr = wString.c_str();
RtlInitUnicodeString(&unicodeString, toPcwstr);
InitializeObjectAttributes(&objAttribs, &unicodeString, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);
objAttribs.Attributes = 0;

const int allocSize = 2048;
LARGE_INTEGER largeInteger;
largeInteger.QuadPart = allocSize;

IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatusBlock;

status = NtCreateFile(
    &lFile,
    GENERIC_ALL,
    &objAttribs,
    &ioStatusBlock,
    &largeInteger,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ, 
    FILE_OPEN,
    FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE, 
    NULL, 
    NULL
);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    printf("CreateFile failed..\n");
    return false;
}
else {
    printf("Library Handle : %p\n", lFile);

    DWORD fileSize = getDllSize(dllPath);

    if (fileSize == 0)
    {
        printf("File size 0.\n");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File size : %d byte.\n", fileSize);

        PVOID FileReadBuffer; 
        FileReadBuffer = new CHAR[fileSize];

        status = NtReadFile(
            lFile,
            NULL,
            NULL, 
            NULL, 
            &ioStatusBlock,
            FileReadBuffer,
            sizeof(FileReadBuffer),
            0, // ByteOffset
            NULL);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            printf("Unable to read the dll...  : %d\n", GetLastError());
            return false;
        }
    }
}}
```

For NtCreateFile :

```
status -> 0
ioStatusBlock : Status      -> 0
                Pointer     -> 0x00000000
                Information -> 1
```

I try NtOpenFile and same result.

For NtReadFile :

```
status -> -1073741811
ioStatusBlock : Status      -> 0
                Pointer     -> 0x00000000
                Information -> 1
```

[Result values right after NtCreateFile function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z2Lf.png)

[Result values right after NtReadFile function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICaVz.png)

Comment: Put a breakpoint just after the `NtReadFile` call and check the return value. `GetLastError()` will not help you here since that's only set when you're using the Windows API, not the Native API.

Answer (score 1):

`if (lFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` - 
you need check `status` returned but not `lFile` and NT never set file handle to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` - so condition always will be FALSE. `OPEN_EXISTING` (3) - wrong constant to [`NtCreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566424(v=vs.85).aspx) - need use `FILE_OPEN`(1) for example or use [`NtOpenFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567011(v=vs.85).aspx). you open file as asynchronous (no `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` or `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NALERT` ) - so faster of all you got `STATUS_PENDING` (0x103) as result of [`NtReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567072(v=vs.85).aspx). so you not enter to `if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))` block for `STATUS_PENDING` but data yet not ready in `FileReadBuffer`.

and next time post all status and ioStatusBlock values

Answer (score 0):

The status code -1073741811 from `NtReadFile` means you passed an `INVALID_PARAMETER`.

[ErrorCodeDescription](https://errorco.de/win32/ntstatus-h/status_invalid_parameter/-1073741811/)

Assigning 0 to the `ByteOffset` parameter fixed the Problem for me;

```
LARGE_INTEGER liBytes = { 0 };
status = SysNtReadFile(pFileHandle, NULL, NULL, NULL, &statusBlock, buffer, fileSize, &liBytes, NULL);
```